# Trying to write a simple fuzzer with Peach to detect a buffer overflow

Tags: linux, security, peach

I'm trying to write a simple fuzzer that detects a buffer overflow. The code I want to fuzz is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buf[256];
memcpy(buf, argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
printf(buf);
}
```

And my current Peach Pit is the following:

```
    <DataModel name="MyString">
                    <String value="">
                    <Analyzer class="StringToken" />
                    </String>
    </DataModel>

    <StateModel name="StateVfolder" initialState="Initial">
            <State name="Initial">
                    <Action type="output">
                            <DataModel ref="MyString"/>
                    </Action>
            </State>
    </StateModel>

    <Agent name="LocalAgent">
            <Monitor class="LinuxDebugger">
                    <Param name="Executable" value="./test"/>
            </Monitor>
    </Agent>

    <Test name="Default">
            <Agent ref="LocalAgent"/>
            <StateModel ref="StateVfolder"/>
            <Publisher class="Console" />

            <Logger class="File">
                    <!-- save crash information in the Logs directory -->
                    <Param name="Path" value="Logs"/>
            </Logger>

            <Strategy class="Sequential" />

    </Test>
</Peach>
```

How can I make this work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. I've found a few references to this exact thing but I can't get the files to work correctly.